# English phrases used in airports, to translate in the language of one's choice

Tags: online-resources, airports, language-barrier

Is there any website, with "sample" phrases in English, to translate that can be used in airports, to assist seniors who don't speak English?

Comment: ...spending more time google on the subject "English phrases used in the airport" - Yes

Comment: @pnuts "Registration", "Transfers", "Baggage Claim", "Immigration", "Toilets" (JK everybody can tell from icons)

Comment: This is the kind of thing generally found in a phrasebook.

Comment: The obvious answer would be to use a translator. There are sites available for each language but not for several. Many international airports display signs in multiple languages anyhow.

Comment: Why "seniors" specifically? Do you specifically need phrases that are oriented toward more old-fashioned ideas and practices, or are you just observing that, in your experience, older people tend not to understand English as much?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just Google "phrasebook airport" and you'll have plenty of results, [for example](http://www.teacherjoe.us/TravelAirport.html):

[image]